# Find all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m^{2}-8m+8$ Is a perfect square

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

I think that this problem is easy, but i am not sure whether my solution is correct or not.

**My solution:**

Set: $m^{2}-8m+8 =x^2$, with $x \in \mathbb{N}$
$$m^{2}-x^{2}=8(m-1)$$
$$\implies 8\mid m^{2}-x^{2}$$
$$\implies 8=m-x$$
This last line is the critical one because i don’t have a proof of this statement.
$$8+x=m$$
If we plug this result to the original equation, we get:
$m=1$ and $m=7$.

Comment: Your approach isn't quite right: just because you have $8$ dividing $m^2-x^2$, you can't conclude that either $8=m-x$ or $8=m+x$. For example, $8$ divides $24=4\times 6$, but doesn't divide either $4$ or $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implication $8\mid m^2-x^2\implies 8=m-x$ does not necessarily hold. Consider, for instance $8\mid 7^2-3^2$, whereas $8\not= 7-3$...

*Hint.*

> $$m^2-8m+8=x^2\iff (m-4)^2-8=x^2\iff (m-4+x)\cdot (m-4-x)=8$$What are the factors of $8$?

Comment: Why i can’t put $8$ And $1$ As a factors?

Comment: You can. Since $8=8\cdot 1=4\cdot 2=-8\cdot (-1)=-4\cdot (-2)$ you only need to check those possibilities keeping in mind that $m-4-x>m-4-x$ (i.e. $m-4-x$ is the greater factor) since $x>0$. For example, the first case would be $$\begin{cases}m-4+x=8\\m-4-x=1\end{cases}\stackrel{I-II}{\implies} 2x=7$$ However $x\in \mathbb N$, so this case yields no solutions... We move on to the second case: $$\begin{cases}m-4+x=4\\m-4-x=2\end{cases}\stackrel{I-II}{\implies} 2x=2\implies x=1\implies m=7$$ We thus found one solution: $(m,x)=(7,1)$. We move on to the third case...

Comment: For cases where the number (here: $8$) has more factors, you can usually leave some of them out. Here you could notice that $m-4+x, m-4-x$ have the same parity. So $m-4+x=8, m-4-x=1$ or $m-4+x=-1, m-4-x=-8$ will yield no solutions. You're left with $4\cdot 2$ and $(-2)\cdot (-4)$ (also: be careful $-2>-4$)

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to do this, if you are interested in a solution:

> Note that $m^2-8m+16$ is a square $x^2=(m-4)^2$. Thus $m^2-8m+8 =x^2-8$ for $x=m-4$.

> However, also note the following: for all integers $y \ge 4$  and any other integer $z$, the following inequality holds: $|y^2-z^2| > 8$.

> So $x^2=(m-4)^2$ can't be larger than 9...Can you finish from here.